# How to put dynamically created multiple iframe in one div to flush them for printing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, printing

I have created multiple iframes, and for printing all of them together, I want to append those to one div, so that it can be used for printing. Could you please provide JavaScript or jQuery code for accessing code.

#### Code for creating iframe dynamically at run-time

```
    var contentDiv = document.createElement("contentDiv" + count++);
                var iframe = $('<iframe>', {
                       src: 'blank.htm',
                       id:  'printFrame',
                       frameborder: '0',
                       border: '0',
                       width: '100%',
                       height: '100%',
                       scrolling: 'no'
                }).appendTo(contentDiv);

var frameNode = contentDiv.lastElementChild;
frameNode.setAttribute("src", url.getURL());
var printFrameDiv = document.getElementById("printContentDiv");
$(printFrameDiv).append(contentDiv);
```

## Code for Printing the content

```
    function onPrint(){
    document.getElementById('printTag').hidden = true;
    var dummyContent = document.getElementById("printContentDiv");
    var iFrame = document.getElementById("printFrame");
    dummyContent.innerHTML = iFrame.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML;
    window.print();
    window.parent.closeMe();
}
```

This code currently printing only first iframe I have created dynamically.

Comment: This looks like a do-it-for-me request, which is usually closed as off-topic here. I wonder if you could be more detailed as to what the problem is, and where you are stuck?

Comment: Basically I want to know, is it possible to access all the iframe content and put it in div. Can you please help me by putting some sample code. How i can achieve this. The above code that i have used for printing content of iframe is able to print one iframe at a time.

Comment: Does the `<iframe>` link to the same domain as the parent?

Comment: yes halfer i have got three iframes on my page. But when i am going for printing it is just printing content of one frame only.

Comment: I don't think you answered my question. For your three iframes, do they all use the same domain as their parent page?